# R recode replace all non maching value to NA, is there any way to escape it

Tags: r

I am using recode and  its working fine as its replace all matching value but I don't want to replace its non-matching value, can someone please help

sample dataset

```
x <- c(1:5, NA)
[1]  1  2  3  4  5 NA
```

now using recode

```
recode(x, '1' = "Hello", .default = "World")
[1] "Hello" "World" "World" "World" "World" NA
```

But this is not my requirement, I want it only change '1' but not remaining records, it should be like that

```
[1]  "Hello"  2  3  4  5 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the assignment

```
x[x==1] <- "Hello"
x
#[1] "Hello" "2"     "3"     "4"     "5"     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

The types need to be the same, so it would be

```
recode(as.character(x), "1" = "Hello")
# [1] "Hello" "2"     "3"     "4"     "5"     NA
```

But you could also just use base R's `replace()`.

```
replace(x, x == 1, "Hello")
# [1] "Hello" "2"     "3"     "4"     "5"     NA
```